# Laravel Integrated - Set Selenium/PhantomJS window size

Tags: php, laravel, selenium, phpunit, phantomjs

I'm using Laravel 5.2 together with the amazing Laracasts/Integrated package. I'm using Selenium as the driver and PhantomJS as the emulator. When I make a screenshot with the snap() method, I get a very small screenshot (400x300). How do I change the size of this screenshot (the window)?

I've tried accessing both the session and driver object from the test, but both return NULL.

My `integrated.json`:

```
{
    "baseUrl": "http://dev.project",
    "selenium": {
        "browser": "phantomjs"
    }
}
```

My test:

```
$this->visit('/')->snap('screenshot.png');
```

So do I have to somehow access the session from my test? Do I have to change default values for PhantomJS? do I add some setting in integrated.json or the phpunit.xml? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!